# Macos Mojave restart got stuck

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, software-update, mojave

I was trying to update my Mac to Mojave but when it was restarting it got stuck and all I see is apple logo. I am not sure what happened and how can I get back to start m Mac. Any help please.

This is what I see in photo below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you didn't shut the lid down while updating it or basically didn't put it to sleep through anyway.

if you didn't, I just recommend waiting.

if still stuck, try reinstalling using recovery mode. which is holding CMD-R just after power up during restart . [Apple support for reference](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)

Comment: Yes definitely wait it out.